# Dyno Hours for paid account and Frequency to call app endpoint

Tags: heroku, account, dyno

I am new to Heroku, created an app and deployed on heroku free account. And I want use endpoint of that app as publicly accessible endpoint. In heroku documentation it is mentioned heroku API can be called for 4500/hour. I am confused that will this limitation will be applicable to publicly accessible endpoint also?

and how much dyno hours do we get for the standard account/paid account ?

Answer (score 0):

The [Platform API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/platform-api) is meant for developers who want to programmatically manage the applications (create/destroy Dynos, etc...). Here the max 4500 calls per hour applies.

There is no rate limit on the endpoints (or applications) you develop and expose to the users. The only limitation is the quota in case you use the [Heroku Free](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#usage) tier.

Paid plans do not have restrictions: Dynos are always running but they do restart every 24hrs anyway (see [Heroku Restart](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting) policy)